# Is it correct to say "don't force the bottle closed/open because the threads of the cap and the bottle don't align well with each other"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Sometimes, when we screw / unscrew a cap on / off a bottle, the external male thread of the neck of the bottle doesn't align well with the internal female thread the cap. And As a result, the cap might get stuck in the middle.

When the cap is stuck in the middle, is it correct to say

"**don't force the bottle closed/open because the threads of the cap and the bottle don't align well with each other**"?

Answer (score 5):

This is a another attempt at a "launch and leave" sentence.  It's correct but it ignores the presence of another English speaker who can understand context or respond if they need more information.

Just say

> Don't force it.

As noted in a comment, the specific phrase for when threads don't align is "cross-threaded".  So you could add

> It's cross-threaded; don't force it.

Comment: It is bad to force things that have become **cross-threaded**.

Comment: Gently remove it and put it on straight.